# How to add URL of GIF and SVG in CSS file of WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress, url, svg, gif

For example, I tried the following code but none of them works:

`background-image: url("images/components/arrows.svg");`

`background-image: url("./images/components/arrows.svg");`

`background-image: url("../images/components/arrows.svg");`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're looking for this...

```
   background-image: url("//images/components/arrows.svg");
```

Comment: @L.Leo

remove the apostrophes in the url()
`background-image: url(//images/components/arrows.svg);`

Comment: This is the standard format `background-image: url(http://example.com/example.svg)` Try it like that, if it doesn't work, there's something else at play.

Comment: @I Love CSS Just solved the problem with `background-image: url(../images/components/arrows.svg);`, thanks for your help!